# Changing method parameter by inheritance

Tags: java, inheritance, methods, parameters

I am looking for a clear and proper way of dealing with a subtle issue. Technicaly yes, I could simply ignore it but that's not the point.

I have a BinaryTree class which utilizes objects of type Node. The BinaryTree class has a method addNode(Node n) which adds a new node according to the rules of a binary tree

Now I want to create a RedBlackTree class which utilizes objects of type RedBlackNode (Node with an additional field for color) and inherits from BinaryTree. I shouldn't just leave the addNode method because it would allow to add a normal Node to the RedBlackTree, causing an error. I could overload the method like this:

```
class RedBlackTree extends BinaryTree
{
   public void addNode(RedBlackNode n)
   {
      ...
   }
}
```

but then the other method is still exposed and ideally it shouldn't be.
I could override the method like this:

```
class RedBlackTree extends BinaryTree
{
   public void addNode(Node n)
   {
      if(n instanceof RedBlackNode)
      {
      ...
      {
   }
}
```

but then the method still takes a normal Node as a parameter and ideally it should only accept RedBlackNode (it could confuse someone else when he tries to use the method).

What I want is to inherit the addNode method in such a way that the parameter type is changed from Node to RedBlackNode. How do I do that? Is that even possible? Or is it a conceptual problem on my side?

Comment: Why not simply use generics? I thought that this sort of situation is what they were added to the language for.

Comment: Pretty much exactly that: `class BinaryTree<N extends Node>` `class RedBlackTree extends BinaryTree<RedBlackNode>`

Answer (score 1):

You could go for something like the following:

```
class BinaryTree<E extends Node>{
    public void add(E e){
    }
}

class RedBlackTree extends BinaryTree<RedBlackNode>{
    @Override
    public void add(RedBlackNode e) {
    }
}
```

Then you can pass any node into your binary tree, but only the specific nodes into your `RedBlackTree`.